# win 8 - network recognition takes 5 min after each reboot

Tags: windows-8, network-shares

After upgrading to Windows 8, it takes about 5 minutes to recognize a network after reboot. During this time the network and sharing center is not responding. Only when the wifi connection or Lan cable is found (after the 5 minutes) is it opening up. This does not seem ok. With Win 7 I never had this issue.